# Image map in HTML

Tags: windows, images, html, offline, maps

I need an offline software (free/paid) for Windows 7, similar to image map in HTML but without code.

I need to click a region on the map to show a real photo of this region, all offline. Or it can be like Google Maps when you click to the bubble a photo will pop out for this location.

Comment: Can you provide more details? You have a map and want to add markers to it, and clicking a marker displays an image? What do you do with this map, where will it be opened? As a local HTML file in a web browser? And adding the images should work without editing HTML? In which format is the map, is it just an image?

Comment: by "image map" at first I thought that it's a map of an image when zoomed in, like the document map for large text files. I think you mean the photo geolocation viewer [like this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/54NDwiF-0fI)

Comment: would an image map generator help you?https://www.image-maps.com/
https://www.image-map.net/
http://maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap/

Comment: Something went wrong editing as far as I can see, bit a strange language I see.

Comment: There are plugins for GIS software that do this. Take a look here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com